# Need help with Differential Equation Question

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$(x^2D^2 + 4xD + 2)y = \log x,$$ given that $x = 1$, $y = 0$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}= 0$.

Comment: This is an Euler differential equation.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 1):

The given equation can be written as

$ x^2 y'' + 4 x y' + 2 y = \log(x) $

This is an Euler differential equation.  To solve it, define $y = \varphi(t)$ where $t = \log(x)$

Then $ y' = \dfrac{d \varphi}{d x} = \dfrac{\dfrac{ d \varphi}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt} } = \dfrac{1}{x} \varphi' $

Similarly, $y'' = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{\varphi'}{x} \right) = \dfrac{ \varphi'' - \varphi' } { x^2 } $

Thus the equation becomes

$ \varphi'' - \varphi' + 4 \varphi' + 2 \varphi = t $

which reduces to

$ \varphi'' + 3 \varphi' + 2 \varphi = t $

The characteristic polynomial of this linear differential equation with constant coefficients is

$ m^2 + 3m + 2 = 0 $

Thus the roots are $m = -2 , m = -1$, hence, the solution is

$ \varphi = c_1 e^{-2t} + c_2 e^{-t} + A + B t $

Where $c_1 , c_2 $ are arbitary.  To determine $A, B$, plug in the solution into the differential equation

$ (0) + 3 (B) + 2 (A + Bt ) = t $

Hence, $B = \frac{1}{2} , A = - \dfrac{3}{4} $

Hence, the solution is now

$ \varphi = c_1 e^{-2 t} + c_2 e^{-t} +\dfrac{1}{2} t - \dfrac{3}{4} $

Plugging in $ t = \log(x) $ and simplifying

$ y = \varphi(t) = \varphi(log(x)) = c_1 \left( x^{-2} \right) + c_2 \left( x^{-1} \right) + \dfrac{1}{2} log(x) - \dfrac{3}{4} $

We are given two initial conditions for $x = 1, y = 0 , y' = 0 $

From the first condition, $ 0 = c_1 + c_2 - \dfrac{3}{4} $

And we also have $y'(1) = -2 c_1 - c_2 + \dfrac{1}{2} = 0 $

Solving the linear system, we find that $ c_1 = -\dfrac{1}{4} , c_2 = 1 $

Hence, the solution is

$ y = - \frac{1}{4} x^{-2} + x^{-1} + \dfrac{1}{2} log(x) - \dfrac{3}{4} $